# How to construct a tuple/record in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, what is the syntax for a type in ATS that corresponds to the following struct in C:

```
struct{ char *name; int age; double height; }
```

Also, how a value of such a type can be constructed in ATS?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a translation:

```
@{ name= string, age= int, height= double }
```

The value of such a type can be constructed as follows:

```
val x = @{name = "hello", age= 3, height= 2.0}
```

However, note that this not a literal translation. 
For instance, the C type `char*` is a pointer to `char`, and that usually means zero-terminated UTF-8 strings, which maps to type `string` in ATS.
 But, it could well mean a buffer, say, in other contexts.

Also, note that in C, you usually initialize records on a field-by-field basis (that is, you declare a variable of record type, and then assign its fields one by one). 
You can do mostly the same thing in ATS, provided that you are prepared to deal with the typechecker complaints.